# Vim: viewing file structure - classes, methods, functions

Tags: vim, ide

So I have this dream, right: I'm doing incredible wizardry in PHP, in vim, and every once in a while I'd want to press some fancy button combination (the longer the better) to be able to navigate through the file, not in boring, line-by-line mode, but in a magnificent overview mode. Feast my eyes on a tree-like list of classes, methods, functions, variables and other wonders of code. Jump from function to function in sheer merriment.

Know ye a way to fulfill my desires?

Sort of like any file structure dialog/view in any arbitrary IDE. Anything?

Comment: Nice wording... lol

Comment: This is what I call a well-formed question. I wasn't interested in neither question nor the answer, and I've read all of it. Twice. +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is reminiscent of [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) and [Ack.vim](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim/) regarding jumping to functions amongst many files. There's also [FuzzyFinder](https://github.com/vim-scripts/FuzzyFinder) or [command-t](https://github.com/wincent/Command-T.git) or [NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/) for file browsing and [Taglist](https://github.com/vim-scripts/taglist.vim) for source code browsing. You can also use `:help foldmethod` to fold all the functions and see them in a "tree-like" fashion that's expandable. Get familiar with `gf` and `* or #` to jump around between files and variables.

Answer (score 11):

[TagBar](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3465) is similar to the aforementioned TagList, in a different way, but it's not *that* good with PHP.

[This very new plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4125) claims to fix the issue. I've never tested it, though.

Answer (score 6):

I use `:set foldmethod=syntax`. `zM` to fold everything up; `zx` to open the fold under the cursor and close other open folds. The `taglist` plugin (as already mentioned) will do more, but folds are a quick win.

Answer (score 2):

[Taglist](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) allows you to do this for open buffers.

Answer (score 1):

While it won't fulfill all your dreams of a world of wizardry filled with fancy buttons on which your eyes can feast on endless trees of source code... [phpfolding.vim](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1623) does a wonderful per file job of automatically folding all functions with a quick F5 (and is still updated after 12+ years)

[image: vimfolding screenshot]